# In Spring mvc application an object returning as responsebody from the controller is not retrieved using jquery ajax method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, model-view-controller

The object is not returned in the ajax method and no exception is thrown..
The code in the controller method:

I am returning a EmployeeBean object from this method as `@Responsebody`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/anki")
public @ResponseBody EmployeeBean hhh(@RequestParam("name")String name){
    System.out.println("new method");
    EmployeeBean e=new EmployeeBean();
    e.setId("1001");
    e.setName("ankita");
    return e;
}
```

The Bean class EmployeeBean

```
package com.controller;

public class EmployeeBean {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the ajax method response is not coming successfully, the URL is correctly matching in the controller.

The javascript code:

```
function abc(){
    alert('here!!');
    $.ajax({
        url:'anki',
        data:({name : "me"}),   
        success:function(data){
            alert('here gain');
            $('#time').html(data.name);
        }
    });
}

<input type="button" name="submit" title="submit" onclick="abc()"/>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: what if you make a non ajax call to that url, say a get request from your browser

Comment: Do you have jackson library in your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have Jackson library in your classpath add it. Add jackson-core-asl-1.6.4 and jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.4 jars